# How to determine if the last_seen_at Time field is great than 1 minute ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Room model I have a field last_activity_at

I want to do something like

if last_activity_at is greater than 1 minute ago?

What's the right way in rails to do that? Thanks

Comment: Strange how rails outputs times differently internally? > 1.minute.from_now
 => Wed, 21 Sep 2011 22:34:19 UTC +00:00 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :017 > Time.now
 => 2011-09-21 15:33:20 -0700

Comment: I tried this but it's not working --- record.last_activity_at > 1.minutes.from_now

Comment: The logic you posted is looking into the future and will never be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
record.last_activity_at > 1.minute.ago
```

Comment: What you see in your console shouldn't matter since Rails should be able to compare the times internally. Is it actually failing?